# Is there a gcloud command to export a spanner database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I would like to automate exports of our Spanner database to Google Cloud Storage. Is this possible using the gcloud SDK? I could not find a command for this.

Is there any other recommended way to back up Spanner databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The export and Import pipelines are Dataflow templates that can be started using the Gcloud command.

See the third paragraph in:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/export
And how to run the template in:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#cloud_spanner_to_gcs_avro
(Select the Gcloud tab in the executing the template section).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do this using gcloud, but it is not a direct Cloud Spanner command. The detailed documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#cloud_spanner_to_gcs_avro).

Essentially you use gcloud to run a Cloud Dataflow job to export or backup your data to GCS using a command like the following:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run [JOB_NAME] \
--gcs-location='gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Cloud_Spanner_to_GCS_Avro' \
--region=[DATAFLOW_REGION] \
--parameters='instanceId=[YOUR_INSTANCE_ID],databaseId=[YOUR_DATABASE_ID],outputDir=[YOUR_GCS_DIRECTORY]
```